# How does Node.js load ECMAScript modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

If `vm.compileFunction` is what serves as the core of Node.js's CommonJS loader, then what function is used to run and load ES modules?

Comment: "*I expect that on-the-fly translation to a CommonJS module is performed*" - no, that's not happening. As you wrote yourself, nodejs **originally** was not compatible with ES6 modules, but it has advanced since and [does support ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (since years)

Comment: @Bergi Nothing I said was inconsistent. On-the-fly transpilation *would* count as compatibility.

Comment: Yes, but there is no transpilation. ES modules are supported natively by the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Here are some links from [nodejs.dev](https://nodejs.dev) that may help.

[ECMAScript Modules (`import` statement)](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v19/esm/)

[CommonJS Modules (using `require()`)](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v19/modules/)

If this was helpful, mark it as accepted.